# Creating Multiple files from a data source in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I have a data source I'm working with in Python. I'd like to save that data to a files such that once a threshold is hit (ie: 1K, 1M) the file is closed and a new file is automatically opened to save the data.

ie:

```
<file handler with buffer 200>
file.write('a'*1000)
```

The line above would generate 5 files based on the data. Is there a pre-built python library that will handle this, or do I need to write one myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a logger framework is too much, you can do it yourself -- shouldn't need more than a dozen lines of code or so. The easiest way to get the size of your file is by calling the `tell()` method of your open file descriptor.

You could also keep track of the bytes being output, but this requires additional logic if your program sometimes appends to a pre-existing file.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on pypi brings up [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/logrotate/0.1.0) which might do what you want, but otherwise I'd suggest writing it yourself, it would be a fairly simple tools to write.

I haven't tested it, but here's a very simple implementation that should do it (python3).

```
class RotatingFile:

    def __init__(self, basename, size, binary=False):
        self.basename = basename
        self.size = size
        self.counter = 0
        if binary:
            self.buffer = b''
        else:
            self.buffer = ''

    def write(self, data)
        self.buffer += data
        if len(self.buffer) >= self.size:
            data = self.buffer[:self.size]
            self.buffer = self.buffer[self.size:]
            name = self.basename + str(self.counter)
            with open(name) as f:
                f.write(data)
            self.counter += 1

    def flush(self):
        name = self.basename + str(self.counter)
        with open(name) as f:
            f.write(self.buffer)
```

So this should write to 6 files:

```
>>> f = RotatingFile('myfile', 1000)
>>> f.write('a' * 5500)
>>> f.flush()
```

Comment: I saw that, but I'd be potentially dealing with binary data as a source and I wasn't sure that would work.

I just want to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel before I impliment this as a tool.

Comment: Then its probably easiest to write it yourself.  But like I said, it should be quite easy.

Comment: Please, when writing Python 2.x code, do inherit from "object" when creating a class